# Percentage buffer around multiline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, buffer

I need to create plugin to QGIS that will draw buffers about width equal 1/2 length each line.

Example (my amateur sketch in MS Paint):
[image]

So, around each lines  be created square

I searched good solution but I found only plugin Buffer by percentage (it works only with polygon) and a few threads about buffer around point but it's not enough for me.

Maybe you have an idea how it could be solved?

I don't need all code, I just don't know what I should do now.

Comment: What's wrong with calculating the length of your line and using a flat cap buffer  of width of length/2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `buffer` geoprocessing tool.

Make sure not to enter a fixed distance, but instead to select an expression and to use half the geometry length (`length($geometry)/2`)

[image]

Comment: Ok, it works if I have a few lines, but I have one polyline. Maybe I should try to split this polyline to lines and later trying this method...and later changing all for code. Thanks very much

Comment: Use processing. You can write simple schema witch input as line, line to segments algorithm and at the end buffer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the provision is already there in QGIS.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html

1. Go to Processing > Toolbox
2. Search for Buffer

This should give you the expected result.

Comment: On this website don't have anything about percentage buffer. I don't have problem with create buffer about specific distance. I want add line layer as input layer (red line on my picture) and get polygon as output layer (area marked green lines)