# Adaptive Buffer Distance Expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, buffer, expression

I have a shapefile of line features that I need to add a buffer to. The width of the buffer will depend on the length of each feature (25% of the feature length). I know I need to create an expression for the buffer distance, but have not been able to come up with the proper expression.  Any idea how to change the expression to come up with the right result?

[image]

I have tried the suggestion shared [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/335700/171912) but the buffers still end up the same width for all of the features.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `length` to `$length`.

`length` is a function which returns the length of any geometry linestring. It is used like this: `length(geometry)`.

`$length` returns the length of the actual line feature.

Comment: There is an option to use length($geometry). The difference is that $length calculates the ellipsoidal lengt (thus taking into consideration the curvature of the earth), whereas length($geometry) calculates the planar length - thus the distance on the projected map canvas in the respective CRS. For short distances as in your case (I guess), that does not really play a role.

Comment: Both  of the expressions work while using the field calculator to determine the line length, so I will mark this as answered. Interestingly, though, when the same expressions are copied to the buffer tool, they do not work. I am running QGIS 3.16.